# Check if database table record with specified id contains a list c#?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table called `PeopleActivityGroup` in SQL.

Say that the table has this data:
[image: Table]

From Front-End I receive an object containing a List of PeopleActivityGroup like this:

```
{
 "peopleId": "PeopleId1"
 "peopleActivityGroupList": [
     {
       "ActivityId ": "ActId4",
     },
     {
       "ActivityId ": "ActId2",
     },
     {
       "ActivityId ": "ActId3",
     },
 ]
}
```

**How can I check if that table, given the** `PeopleId` **contains each** `ActivityId` **from the list?**

---

In the end, it would be that if my `query == null` then I know there is no element corresponding to that list of `ActivityId` for that `PeopleId`.

Otherwise, my query will return all the `ActivityIds` for that `PeopleId`?

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = PeopleActivityGroup.Where(t=>t.PeopleId==peopleId).Select(t=>t.ActivityId).Tolist();
```

Comment: Thanks, after posting the question i immediately realized the answer i was looking for. I will mark this as the correct answer because it is. Cheers!